# Microsoft Chart - Using FastLine instead of StepLine for high performance?

Tags: .net, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm using Microsoft Chart in order to draw some stepline charts.

Should I use StepLine directly or should i make my own using FastLine in order to be faster ?

In other words, do anyone know if the stepline is built on the Line or on the FastLine type.

I've got around several thousands points to draw.

StepLine : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456618.aspx

FastLine : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489249.aspx

It's seems to have good performance with StepLine too.

Comment: Doesn't it just look like a blob when you use StepLine on thousands of points?

Comment: Yes, and the aim is not drawing this way :p but to show signal's activities, so if it's drawing we can zoom easily on it.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem, I have 670,000 points.

I tried stepline with 670,000 points, in order to draw the same graph, I had to use 670,000*2 points for fast line.

And the result is, in release mode, I tested 5 times (the time varies a lot, i guess it's cache) fastline costs around 70% of the time spent by stepline

Comment: the best way is definitevely to sample your data depending on your zoom.

Comment: Yes, but the amount of showed points should be indexed on the zoom.

Comment: @ykatchou Here is another problem, if I call zoom right after addXY all the points, it wouldn't work. I think it's because another thread is dealing with the points. I don't know when should I call zoom.